# What to do when an anonymous user inserts valuable information that should be a comment

Tags: support

Today I was a bit lost when I went through my review queue and [stumbled upon this case.](https://superuser.com/a/142175/50173)

[image]

You may disagree that the information itself isn't that valuable and I should just reject the edit, maybe. But imagine a case similar to this where the information *is* valuable.

The review tools let me: Approve, Reject, Improve or Skip. None of these work if I want to inform a moderator to convert the edit content to a comment. I am aware that anonymous users haven't the right to comment.

Then I thought: Maybe a *Reject* together with a custom message would fit. Another user had the same idea already. But will this custom message be directed to a mod? I don't think so.

[image]

In the end I skipped. I do not want to post a comment in the name of another (anonymous) user, because I can't be sure if the information is correct. And I also do not want to convert the initial answer to a community wiki or post a new answer as community wiki. Its clearly only a comment.

In short: How should I react here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reject. An edit is never the right way to object an answer. The user could just as well posted their own answer instead of editing an existing one.

If you feel so inclined, you can copy the content to a new post to preserve it.